# Analytic approximation $\int_0^1 \frac{P_3(t)}{\sqrt{1-k^2 P_3^2(t)}}dt$

Tags: integration

I have the following integral:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{P_3(t)}{\sqrt{1-k^2 P_3^2(t)}}dt$$
where $P_3(t)$ is a third-degree polynomial with all coefficients different from zero and $k$ a generic constant. This integral, once known coefficients and the constant $k$, can be integrated numerically, but I wonder if, in some research work, this integral was approximated analytically (under some assumptions on coefficients and the constant $k$).

Thanks in advance.

**Edit (suggested by IgorKhavkine's comment).**

If $P(t)=a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$, $a$ is very large respect other constants. The coefficient $d$ is $<0$ and very small respect to $c,b$. Coefficients $c,b$ are comparable.

Comment: Are any of the constants in your problem very large or very small? Otherwise, there's not much that analytical methods could do.

Comment: Google hyperelliptic integral?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine. If $P(t)=a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$, $a$ is very large respect other constants. The coefficient $d$ is $<0$ and very small respect to $c,b$. Coefficients $c,b$ are comparable.

Comment: Then probably a power series expansion, like in Robert Israel's answer, is your best bet. Though, given what you wrote, $(P(t)-a)/a$ might be a better expansion parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could expand in a series in powers of $k$:

$$ \dfrac{P(t)}{\sqrt{1-k^2 P(t)^2}} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{(2j)! 4^{-j}}{j!^2} k^{2j} P(t)^{2j+1} $$